# How to tame case sensitivity of Power BI function name

Tags: function, powerbi, dax, case-sensitive, m

I am new to using Power BI. I just noticed I cannot call Power BI functions following the case-sense used in the Power BI doc.

For example Date.YEAR([creation_date]) yields an error as Date.YEAR is not recognized. But Date.Year([creation_date]) works fine.

My question is how do I set Power BI to accept both functions names?

Comment: This is in the query editor, right?

Comment: Yes in the query editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mention "case-sense used in the Power BI doc", I'm guessing you're referring to DAX functions used to write measures (e.g. [`YEAR()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/year-function-dax)). DAX is indeed not case-sensitive and you can use whatever you prefer.

However, `Date.Year([creation_date])` appears to be M language code (see [`Date.Year`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/date-year)) that is used in the query editor. The M language is case-sensitive and I don't think there is an easy way around it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links, they were so resourceful.